# Paypal Standard

Tags: contributions, paypal

Drupal 7 CiviCRM 5.6.0

I have now tried PayPal_standard instead of express. Payment goes all the way through. I select return to merchant, which goes to a civicrm thank you page and I get this error instead:

*Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.*

Report log shows: $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => [code] => )

Can anyone help as we can't take any PayPal donations at the moment.

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Gareth, Are there any custom php or customization or extension on your site?

Comment: Are the payments arriving in PayPal?